# Where was Maaeser Sheni brought before the beit hamikdash was built?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem

This was eaten in Yerushalayim, but prior to the beit hamikdash what was done? I haven't seen an answer to this. Any sources would be great.

Answer (score 6):

The *Mishna*, [*Z'vachim* 14](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%93):6, q.v., says *maaser sheni* was brought to the *mishkan* at *Shilo*. The commentaries to 14:7 indicate that when the *mishkan* was in *Nov*, and when it was in *Giv'on*, *maaser sheni* was eaten anywhere in Israel and didn't need to be brought anywhere.